# how to shift windows forms controls?

Tags: c#, winforms

How can i get same functionality in windows forms as in the next example. When i  have two links one beneath, and when i click first link a panel is visibleunder it and next link is shifted. When i click again the panel is invisible and second link shifted back.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function toggleDivState(divName)
   {
      var ctl = window.document.getElementById(divName);
      if (ctl.style.display == "none")
         ctl.style.display = "";
      else
         ctl.style.display = "none";
   }
  </script>

<a href="javascript:toggleDivState('poll<%# Eval("ID") %>');">
<div style="display: none;" id="poll<%# Eval("ID") %>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?
on click:

```
control1.Visible = !control1.Visible;
control2.Visible = !control1.Visible;
```

??

Comment: This won't help. The second link should shift down.

Answer (score 0):

You can use panels that have the '[Dock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock.aspx)' property said to 'Top' - you can then adjust the height of said panel to suit.

Comment: if i set the Dock property of panel to 'Top' it docks to parent control , which is Form. And i want to see the panel under the link if i click the link

Comment: You could just have another panel docked above that, if needs be?

Answer (score 0):

Sound like you need a [FlowLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zah8ywcc.aspx) with `FlowDirection = TopDown`.

Put within this Panel your Link, Panel, Link2 and Panel2. Within the LinkClick event you set the `Panel.Visible = !Panel.Visible`.